# Custom npm package in typescript: cannot find name of custom interface

Tags: typescript, npm

I have angular app in typescript built with webpack. 
Also I have npm package (hosted in Sinopia not npm) with next structure

```
my-custom-npm-package
- index.ts
- studentStorage.ts
- student.d.ts
```

**student.d.ts**

```
interface IStudent
{
    name: string;
    id: number;
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import { StudentStorage } from './studentStorage';
export { StudentStorage }
```

**studentStorage.ts**

```
export class StudentStorage{
    private students: IStudent[] = [];

    public get(): IStudent[]{
        return this.students.slice(0);
    }   
}
```

In my angular component I have this string

```
import { StudentStorage } from 'my-custom-npm-package';
```

Next I get this error with webpack

```
ERROR in D:\Sandbox\MultiLanguage\node_modules\my-custom-npm-package\studentStorage.ts
(2,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IStudent'.
```

I have workaround:
Create typings.d.ts where I write

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/my-custom-npm-package/student.d.ts" />
```

But I want to use my custom npm package without this fix. 
I want installation  without referencing .d.ts files.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would probably be to add `/// <reference path="student.d.ts" />` to `studentStorage.ts`.  But it's weird to have `IStudent` global while the rest of your library is in modules.  I'd suggest making `student.d.ts` into a module by changing it to:

```
export interface IStudent
{
    name: string;
    id: number;
}
```

and `studentStorage.ts` to:

```
import { IStudent } from "./student";
export class StudentStorage{
    private students: IStudent[] = [];

    public get(): IStudent[]{
        return this.students.slice(0);
    }   
}
```

Then clients of your library that want to use `IStudent` will just have to import it.